# Closing workbook, catch Cancel event

Tags: excel, vba

I have code for `Workbook_BeforeClose` event. I like how it works now but I have just noticed a problem with `Application.Visible = False`. When I click Yes, it saves Workbook, when I click No, it does nothing, but when I click Cancel it already done `Application.Visible = False` and I can't see Excel application. How to fix that?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

On Error Resume Next

        Application.Visible = False

        Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
        ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True

        ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="123456"

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Start").Visible = True

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Start").Activate

        ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="123456", Structure:=True, Windows:=False

  End Sub
```

Comment: i don't think you even Need those Lines. Can't you remove them ?

Comment: I know I can remove `Application.Visible = False` and sleep well but it just looks more cool when Excel is not visible and all these operations with Visible and password protection are happening in the background.

Comment: Instead of hiding the app, why not turn off screen updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on the built-in dialog, try using your own. That way you have more control of what happens and when.

So maybe something like:

```
Dim closing As Boolean
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not closing Then
        answer = MsgBox("Save data?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, "Save data?")

        If answer = vbYes Or answer = vbNo Then
            closing = True
            ' your code here
            ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=answer = vbYes
        Else
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Good one! Is there any possibility to disable completely built-in dialog so user will see only this one? Now after this one comes built-in dialog box.

Comment: @user7202022 If there aren't any unsaved changes I don't think the built in dialog should pop up, so the `ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=answer = vbYes` line is supposed to make sure that any changes are saved or abandoned before it gets to the built in one.
Is it possible that your code is changing the workbook in some way after that line? It worked for me in a very basic test.

Comment: I have added application.displayalerts command. Build in dialog is popping up when I press cancel. If I use Yes or No, then everything is fine.

Comment: @user7202022 Did you keep the bit about setting Cancel to true if it's cancelled? 
The line:
`Cancel = True`
Otherwise I'm not sure I'm afraid